# how markup / change next button in multiple pages in DataStudio?

Tags: looker-studio

Is there any option how to  markup / change (attribute, text...) of  in multiple pages in DataStudio ?
If I use embed option to insert report to my website, then the  on the bottom  can be overlooked, 
Or if I want change text to > `next page : Geomap`... ?

Here is my new site https://webcovid19.live/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own hyperlink buttons in the UI to navigate to next or previous pages. [Dynamic page links](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7054323?hl=en) explains more. You should be able to change the format of these hyperlinks you create.